# Opencv zbar python scanner error

Tags: python, opencv, zbar

```
import zbar
import Image
import cv2

# create a reader
scanner = zbar.ImageScanner()
# configure the reader
scanner.parse_config('enable')
#create video capture feed
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, cv = cap.read()
    cv = cv2.cvtColor(cv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    pil = Image.fromarray(cv)
    width, height = pil.size
    raw = pil.tostring()
    # wrap image data
    image = zbar.Image(width, height, 'Y800', raw)

    # scan the image for barcodes
    scanner.scan(image)

    # extract results
    for symbol in image:
        # do something useful with results
        print 'decoded', symbol.type, 'symbol', '"%s"' % symbol.data

# clean up
print "/n ...Done"
```

I ran this code but this shows this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joeydash/Desktop/InterIIT-UAV-challenge/zbar/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    raw = pil.tostring()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 695, in tostring
    "Please call tobytes() instead.")
Exception: tostring() has been removed. Please call tobytes() instead.
```

Don't know what it means by image.tostring function. How can I solve this?

Comment: did you try doing what the Exception says? replace ```tostring()``` with ```tobytes()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All credit to mark jay's comment. Your code will look like this

```
import zbar
import Image
import cv2

# create a reader
scanner = zbar.ImageScanner()
# configure the reader
scanner.parse_config('enable')
#create video capture feed
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, cv = cap.read()
    cv = cv2.cvtColor(cv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    pil = Image.fromarray(cv)
    width, height = pil.size
    raw = pil.tobytes()
    # wrap image data
    image = zbar.Image(width, height, 'Y800', raw)

    # scan the image for barcodes
    scanner.scan(image)

    # extract results
    for symbol in image:
        # do something useful with results
        print 'decoded', symbol.type, 'symbol', '"%s"' % symbol.data

# clean up
print "/n ...Done"
```

Notice how the line 
`raw = pil.tostring()`
has been changed to
`raw = pil.tobytes()`

Hope this helps!